# JDBC's rs.getString() won't return the value of the query result

Tags: java, mysql, sql, web-services, jdbc

I have some problems with JDBC's rs.getString("column_name") basically it would not assign the value recieved from the query result, I have a String **ris** which is supposed to get the row name from rs.getString, for semplicity of the question I'm using **ris** and my query returns only one row. This is the code:

```
         //It returns null, or any other values I use to initialize the variable 
         String ris=null;

         q = "SELECT DISTINCT nome FROM malattia WHERE eta='" + age + "' AND sesso='" + sexstr + "' AND etnia='" + etniastr + "' AND sintomi IN(" + tes + ")";

                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(q);
                    if (!rs.last()) {
                          ris = "no";
                                     } 
                    else {

                      //This is the place where I'm having problems
                        while(rs.next()){
                      //ris is supposed to get the name of the query result having column "nome"
                        ris=rs.getString("nome");

                                      }
                         }


              conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
              ris = e.toString();
        }

         return ris;
```

I semplified the code, so it would be easy to focus on where the problem is.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you try to read something from the column (as I see from the code) or you want to read some metadata (as I see from the comments)?

Comment: I will try rs.getString(1) and see if it helps, i checked the column name.rs.last is the part to see if the query returns zero rows, then to return ris="no"

Comment: @Dmitry Alexandrov I'm trying to use the query result, in this case(which i semplified) I get one row as a result, the row is a String and i want to assign the variable "ris" this row value

Comment: If you format your code it makes it a lot easier for others to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, just remove the `rs.last()` call in the if condition.. also i agree with @Thilo about using prepared statements.

```
 String ris=null;

         q = "SELECT DISTINCT nome FROM malattia WHERE eta='" + age + "' AND sesso='" + sexstr + "' AND etnia='" + etniastr + "' AND sintomi IN(" + tes + ")";

                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(q);
                    rs.first(); // go to first record.
                      //This is the place where I'm having problems
                        while(rs.next()){
                      //ris is supposed to get the name of the query result having column "nome"
                        ris=rs.getString("nome");

                                      }
                         }


              conn.close();
```

Comment: Just tried it, it works! the problem indeed was with the last().Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
if (rs.last())
   while (rs.next())
```

That won't work, because after you have called `last` , you are at the last row and  `next` will always return `false` (it would return `true` and take you to the next row if there was one left).

And please use a prepared statement with bind variables!

And finally close ResultSet and Connection (or use Jakarta Commons DbUtils).

Comment: +1 for what i believe is the right answer and also for the prepared statement advice

Comment: Yes indeed, the problem was with last(), very well explained and yes i'll re implement is using prepared statement. Thanks!